# Locust: how to share data between two different types of users

Tags: locust

I have a system where there are two types of entities - **parent and child**.

When a parent goes into a particular state, it creates one or more child entities and the child entities then go through their state changes independent of each other and the parent. The main thing to note is that when a parent spawns off a child, he also assigns an **id** to it and the child has to use that **id** while going through the state changes.

So, in my locustfile, I created two different classes as below:

```
class ParentLocust(Locust):
     task_set = ParentTaskSet


class ChildLocust(Locust):
    task_set = ChildTaskSet
```

My question is that when an instance ofo the `ParentLocust` issues the REST call which leads to the creation of a child entity, how can the `id` of the **child entity** be conveyed to a `ChildLocust` instance?

My first thought was to use a global dictionary, where the key is the `parent_id` and the value is a `list` containing the different `child_id`. Now, an instance of the `ChildLocust` gets assigned a random `child_id` by doing a random lookup in the dictionary and then removes it from the dictionary as well (so that no other `ChildLocust` gets assigned the same `child_id`). But I am not sure if this is correct, because there are two many instances (parent as well as child) accessing the same dictionary at the same time.

Comment: It kind of feels like you are trying to use Locust to write scripts rather than the purpose of Locust, which is to define user behavior (on a Locust class) and then allow those _users_ to interact with your site.

Comment: While I understand what you are saying, from what I have read, Locust is not just for testing websites. It is to stress test any HTTP system. I am defining the behavior of the parent and child in their own classes because they are kind of independent, the only thing is that for the child behavior to be simulated, I need the child id from the parent.